# Talking about future in the past

Tags: tense-agreement

Imagine I had a dream when I was kid. Now I am adult so I talk about it which I couldn't fulfilled and will not able to.

Which tense should I use in the blank?

> I too did have some childish dreams like every kid like being
>   astronaut and going to moon when I ... adult.

Comment: Did you have a particular word in mind (regardless of tense) for the blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I *had* some childish dreams like every kid, like being *an* astronaut and going to moon when I **become** *an* adult.

Though it is in the future from the child's timeframe, as an "adult", "being an astronaut and going to moon" would be in the present.

Comment: I was thinking of the words become or be.